# Vuforia model target preview

Tags: model, target, preview, vuforia

Is there a way to change the material that the model target preview uses? The project I am working on utilizes UPR which is not compatible with the standard material on the preview.

I tried turning the material into a UPR material but the  material is locked down.

Comment: I assume you are using Unity. If yes this is more like a Unity question than a Vuforia engine question. I suggest to add the unity-game-engine tag